Apecar si declina al maschile o al femminile?
Ciao,
l'Apecar (il famoso tre ruote della Piaggio), si declina al maschile o al femminile?
Normalmente mi è sempre parso di sentirlo appellato al maschile, ma è anche vero che è costruzione con Ape (che va al femminile).
Il problema mi si pone, perché devo metterci un articolo indeterminativo davanti e quindi ci sta l'apostrofo che a seconda la declinazione va o non va.
Grazie in anticipo!

Su Google Libri appare sia al maschile che al femminile.

Usually, it depends on an implicit word: una Panda (automobile), un panda (animale).

@apaderno nel caso della panda mi sembra più semplice, ma apecar non saprei, mi sembra maschile ma non ne sono certo

Da notare che Apecar è il nome del modello prodotto nel 1971. Tutti gli altri sono Piaggio Ape. Wikipedia dice: «1971 - Apecar, modello sempre a tre ruote ma con scocca e cabina di dimensioni assai maggiori rispetto agli altri modelli, paragonabili a quelle dei camioncini a quattro ruote, con guida tramite volante (diventando il primo Ape a non adottare il classico manubrio) e motore posteriore di 220 cm³». In quella frase, la parola sottointesa può essere «modello».

Sempre da Wikipedia: «1956-1967 - Ape C: motore sempre di 150 cm³ ma profondamente rinnovata per tutto il resto. È la prima Ape dotata di cabina chiusa e portiere (inizialmente previste come optional, ma divenute standard in pochi anni).» In quel caso, presumo usi il femminile per la stessa ragione per cui viene usato in «1948-1952 - Ape A: simile a una Vespa con cassone, motore di 125 cm³, cassone in legno, mozzo della ruota anteriore a sinistra del parafango e cambio a bacchetta.»

@apaderno grazie per i commenti

Come è stato ricordato in un commento, “Apecar” a rigore è un singolo modello, anche se a volte viene usato in modo più generico.
In ogni caso, direi che sia “Apecar” (o “Ape car”) che “Ape” (sempre parlando del veicolo) siano usati al femminile. Per “Ape” lo attesta addirittura il dizionario Zingarelli (vedi schermata in basso); per “Apecar” considererei attendibile questo sito di noleggiatori e collezionisti: https://langellagroup.com/

